# Delphi XE не опознает процедуру CreateOleObject

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, ole

Требуется подключиться к какому-нибудь офисному приложению через ole (скажем, к word), что делаем в таком случае? Всё просто, помещаем в переменную типа `Variant` выражение `CreateOleObject('Word.Application')` и дальше по накатанной. Но так оно только кажется. Процедуру `CreateOleObject` он не опознаёт, благополучно выдаёт ошибку - компиляция прерывается. Теперь лезем в Delphi 7 открываем созданный в Delphi XE проект... после непродолжительной ругани (непродолжительной, т.к. проект – пустая форма) программа благополучно компилится, `CreateOleObject` срабатывает нормально. Но на этом мы не останавливаемся – снова лезем в Delphi XE, открываем перекомпиленный проект – и снова всё замечательно. Никакие новые модули не подключаются, что происходит – непонятно.

То есть в итоге всё работает, но наверняка этого можно было добиться и другими методами. Хотелось бы узнать, что я делаю не так и что надо делать.
ОС – Windows 7 Ultimate x64 (если это имеет значение).

Comment: Вообще, работая с automation надо использовать OleVariant, а не Variant.

Comment: Спасибо, учту

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все намного проще: просто подключите модуль
ComObj.

Comment: О_О Спасибо огромное, помогло! Всё оказалось действительно просто :) Дело в том, что в описанном мною варианте delphi 7 comobj почему-то не подключал, вот я и думал...

Comment: В delphi 7 CreateOleObject в другом юните было (непомню в каком но он по умолчанию подключался) а ComObj это промежуточное решение типа для облегчения перехода на XE и далее, я на это грабли в 2010ой версии наступил.